# What the meaning of good days

Tags: vocabulary

On a lot of my inbox emails, I get on the top of email "good days", I suppose it should be good day not good days .. why they add s to day ?

Comment: Do you by any chance have an idea what the senders' native language is?

Comment: I'm guessing that by "on the top of email" you mean that the salutation reads "good days". It seems like an error to me.

Comment: Without further context, it's not possible to know the writer's intent.  Is "good day" being used as a salutation?

Comment: Can you provide an example of one of these emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **good old days** refers to a time in the past when things in general seemed better than things seem now.  It is *nostalgia*.

P.S. The term can be used ironically, and so the nostalgia could be mock nostalgia. It would depend on the context.

Comment: **good old days** is a collocation. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22good%20old%20days%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en